# C++ sockets sending structures

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, structure

I can send/receive data over sockets using a char array but can't figure out a way to send structures . I found a lot of articles but they are to hard to understand .. As far as I know we have to use a function called snprintf to make packets of data and then some other to revive it . Please I am looking for a very reliable but simple way of data transfer .. Here is some code I wrote to send via char array

```
int main()
{
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

    char sendBuff[1025];
    time_t ticks;
    printf("\n\n...Server is starting up...\n\n");
    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(4567);

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    printf("Bind successful\n");
    listen(listenfd, 10);
    printf("Ready: Waiting for clients\n");
    while(1)
    {
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); 
        ticks = time(NULL);
        snprintf(sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));
        write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff));
        close(connfd);
        sleep(1);
    }
```

Client

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd = 0 /*Socket Descriptor*/, n = 0;
    char recvBuff[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

    if(argc != 2)  {
        printf("\n Usage: %s <ip of server> \n",argv[0]);
        return 1;
    } 

    memset(recvBuff, '0',sizeof(recvBuff));
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
        return 1;
    } 

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr)); 
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(4567); 
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0) {
        printf("\n inet_pton error occured\n");
        return 1;
    } 

    if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
       printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
       return 1;
    } 

    while ( (n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0) {
        recvBuff[n] = 0;
        if(fputs(recvBuff, stdout) == EOF) {
            printf("\n Error : Fputs error\n");
        }
    } 

    if(n < 0) {
        printf("\n Read error \n");
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here is keyword useful for googling for solution of your problem - **serialization**.

Comment: @arrowdodger revolving around that word for 6 hours now can't figure out an easy way

Comment: What about Boost.Serialization? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Comment: Serialization is essentially the problem of figuring out how to convert a type to and from char array so that you can use things like sockets and files.  Maybe you could post a particular type you're trying to serialize, and what you've tried, to get started with a concrete example.

Comment: @lfti: It's not an easy problem.  The easiest solution is to give each struct its own send function which sends all of its members, that way you don't need to worry about memory.  You lose flexibility this way, however, and it requires a lot of extra boilerplate.

Comment: As arrowdodger said: Boost.Serialization is probably want you want. If you plan on doing portable networking, I would like to add Boost.Asio to that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For sending structures, in summary: **don't**. As in, don't attempt to take a structure pointer, the sizeof operator, and a socket send() and expect things will all work out fine, because even if it looks like it works, its already broken in design.

Rather, your structure members should be laid out in a well-defined byte-format that is understood and managed on *both* ends of the socket connection by common code that is *portable*. This format (e.g. the protocol) should have portable routines for *both* assembling your structure into a byte array, and disassembling it out of one. Using these routines on both the client and server side, accounting for sizes, endianness of numeric values, etc, is ultimately the only way to to this both (a) right, and (b) portable.

There are generic solutions available (such as boost::serialization), but ultimately there is no silver bullet. So consider *all* options and go with the most portable, *simplest* approach you can.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this approach.

Use google protocol buffer. A quick link on how to do that is mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial)

You can make ur own messages and then transmit these messages over sockets udp/tcp.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use an application that does code generation based on a interface description language (IDL). Two excellent options are [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) and [Google protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).